# How to send reminder emails using journey builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I have 3 tables namely Customer, cust_activity, meetings
and I have already sent emails to Customers regarding meetings happening in their city.(using journey builder).

Now i want to send reminder emails 2 days before using journey builder to those who subscribed for meetings.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: I see that your customer table is called Customer, and I guess meetings is a data extension containing a list of all available meetings, but what is on cust_activity? Is this the table which holds individual bookings?

Comment: Yes TCassa,  cust_activity table will have field " activity_meeting_id " which is nothing but a meeting_id in the meeting table. example:- if customer has subscribed for 2 different meetings then cust_activity table will have 2 records with different activity_meeting_id and activity_no.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a table for customers, a table for bookings, and a table for meetings, you could write a query to create a new data extension to use for a 'reminder' journey. I do something similar for reminding people 4 weeks, 2 weeks or 1 week away from an event.

I don't know your schema, but you can create something similar to the following: You'll basically need the email address and the meeting date (I'm not sure where you store this) in one data extension. Then you can run this every day to add people to the journey 2 days before the event.

```
SELECT EmailAddr, MeetingDate
FROM Cust_Activity
WHERE [MeetingDate] >= DATEADD(DAY, 2, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
AND [MeetingDate] < DATEADD(DAY, 3, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
```

Comment: good idea @Tcassa even i am thinking same, get the details of customer and meeting in to one table (who has subscribed for meetings) using query and run a automation everyday. same DE i can use entry source for Journey Builder right. this logic will work right.